# py2neo: How to retrieve node label

Tags: neo4j, label, cypher, nodes, py2neo

How can I acces the label of a node object with py2neo? So, if I have a node `(N:someLabel)`, how can I read out `someLabel`? Can't find this in the documentation and it is not `node["label"]`.

Answer (score 2):

While in other cases attributes are accesed via a dictionary like interface in this case it is `node.labels` which returns a set of labels.

Comment: The result in `py2neo V3` is a `SetView`.  To extract the `node` label itself I converted it into a `list()` and then extracted the first element .

Answer (score 2):

`node.labels()` returns the labels, but as said by [Mr. Berry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5817977/joseph-berry), the SetView needs to be converted into a list.

```
labels_SetView = node.labels()
labels_list = list(labels_SetView)
```

Or you can do it inline:

```
labels_list = list(node.labels())
```

Then, all you need is to iterate:

```
for label in labels_list:
    do something with the label
```

More details in [Py2neo V3](https://py2neo.org/v3/)